# Is it ok for a class to keep a reference on its container?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, containers

I am in the process of creating a very simple RTS game as a personal project. I have done some experimental work up until now and my tiles, camera and unit movement are working fine :)

However, I wanted to add features to the unit selection system and it brought some questions. I have a Player class containing the list of units, but I wanted to create a Squad class, mainly to have some groups made and attribute shortcuts to access those groups easily. If I want to add a unit in a group, I have to remove the unit from it's current group before adding it to the new one. The AddUnit method will be in the Squad class, but I don't want to search in all the others squad for each new unit I add to check and remove the unit. What if I keep the reference to the owner squad inside the Unit class? It would then be removed more easily, but is that ok? The same problem occurs if I want to transfer a unit to another player, can I keep a reference to the player in the unit? Well, I know I can, but would that be acceptable? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's acceptable and it's a good idea to have 2-way references. From container to item and from item to container. When you do something with item (Unit in your example) it's so much easier to get its container without searching for this item in all containers. Getting reference from unit would be simpler, faster, more readable - it's simply better design.

Comment: Another alternative - depending on the abstraction level you're going to - use some kind of event-handler pattern, so the `Squad` registers a "remove listener" with each of its `Unit`s.  The `Unit` that wishes to switch `Squad`s calls that listener first, then adds itself to the new `Squad`.

Comment: That's good then. However, if i need to scrap a squad (remove it from my list of squads), each units that was in that squad will still reference it... Do I absolutly have to iterate each unit in the squad and set the squad reference to null before removing it from the list?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, I thought about the observer/observable classes, but thought the notifyobserver() method was too generic for my needs. However, I could implement my own type of listener interface.

Comment: @Amaranth another option is having a class that represents relation unit-squad, but that would require search for those relations everytime that you whould like to change it - remove or add new one. But it will result in loose coupling between unit and squad - you could introduce other relation types without the need to make new fileds containing new references.

Comment: A class representing a unit-squad relation would be more natural in a DB, no? Anyway, after reading the suggestions, I'll probably have a Player class containing a Squad list and a Unit list, plus a dictionnary in the Player class (Unit as Key, Squad as Value). Squad and Unit classes would have a reference toward the Player (which have very low chances to be deleted). The Player class would be able to give all units in the same squad as a unit passed in parameter (method used by unit or squad). Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 3):

If your language supports it, you should use a weak reference so the container can be freed properly without having to explicitly set the unit's squads to null, which is error prone.

Comment: I did not know about those to be honest. I checked and they are available in C#, so I'll probably explore that possibility. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @dantuch in saying that it is generally acceptable, only you can decide if it's a good idea at this point, depending on how tight you want to couple the concepts of Units and Squads (and Players).

Does it make sense to talk about a Unit without a Squad? Or without a Player?

I realize that I'm answering your question with additional questions, but try to think about your model in an abstract way and you will realize if it is acceptable to tightly couple these concepts or if it's preferable to use something like the observer pattern as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Actually, my game logic make it so that a unit can exist without a squad. Before, it could also exist without a player, but I created an other player instance for the neutral units.